# Customer name is not displayed after login in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer

Customer name is not displayed after successful login in Magento 2.
It only displays the default welcome message.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you have to do its using your own method inside phtml file, This is comman issue in magento 2 many times after login not display customer name, You have to check if customer is login then get customer name from object and set using php way.

Answer (score 3):

try to override the theme header file in your theme:

**app/design/frontend/

{YOUR VENDOR} / {YOUR THEME} / Magento_Theme / templates / html / header.phtml**

1. copy the content from the original file:

   **/ vendor / magento / module-theme / view / frontend / templates / html / header.phtml**
2. add this at the very top of the header.phtml file:

```
<script>
        require([
            'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
        ], function (customerData) {
            'use strict';
                customerData.reload(['customer']);
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

**Customer name is not displayed after login in magento 2**

This issue because of cache (I think your cache is disabled), enable cache it should work.

**problem:** When I turn off the cache system (all types of them), which cause heavy loading each time i refresh a page. In return, it affects the **javascript / knockoutjs** to work properly I think. The part for customer name in `Magento_Customer/templates/account/customer.phtml` is `<span data-bind="text: customer().fullname"></span>`