# How to display customer name when logged in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, customer-session

I am trying to display a customer's name after login (M2 version)

**Question:** How do I display a customer's name after login in Magento 2?

I see here it is a little more difficult: [Customer name is not display after login in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140884/customer-name-is-not-display-after-login-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I customised to login logout and it is working well but I need customer name 
two thing I used for customised

> 1) link.php
>
> 2) authorization.phtml

I have such code in link.php:

```
if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
     return parent::_toHtml();
     }
     return '<div><a ' . $this->getLinkAttributes() . ' >' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getLabel()) . '</a></div>';
    }
```

Comment: i need name of customer  with this please help

Answer (score 10):

There are two way

1. Using object manager into your phtml file:

   ```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

   if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
       $customerSession->getCustomerId();  // get Customer Id
       $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
       $customerSession->getCustomer();
       $customerSession->getCustomerData();

       echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();  // get  Full Name
      echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail(); // get Email
   }
   ```
2. Construct customer session class into your relevant block and create a function to get Customer name. Then call your block function from your phtml file.

Comment: Awesome, thanks :)

Comment: Method 1 may make website slow. Better to use the method 2

Answer (score 6):

Use the below function in your helper file with `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` to get session object  in $customerSession

```
public function getLoggedinCustomerName(){

        if($customerSession->getData('customer_id'))
        {
            $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerSession->getData('customer_id'));
            return $customer->getFirstname();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Guest";
        }
    }
```

and in use it in your PHTML file

```
<?php
$customerName = $helper->getLoggedinCustomerName();
?>
 <a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('customer/account/'); ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo 'Hello '. $customerName; ?></span>
            </a>
```

Comment: Using Helper is a better options. Good Answer

Comment: @AskBytes Use of helper classes are deprecated in 2.3 , Please opt for viewModel implementation  . this is quite old answer . Please let me know if you need more info. Cheers !!

Comment: Yes, i need a solution on viewmodel implementation.

Comment: Hi, Please share the viewModel implementation that will be greatly Appreciated.

Comment: @AskBytes please gave look at this article https://markshust.com/2019/03/13/magic-pass-through-viewmodels-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

Php Block --

```
$customer =  $this->customerRepository->getById($this->customerSession->getCustomerId()); 


echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($customer)->toHtml()
```

Some case:
Bug of Magento 2 when you turn on caches. You must reload customer sections when customer logged in. Check **etc/sections.xml** and **customer-data.js** you will know how to reload customer sections. 
Regards.

I will update related link later.